# "nircmd.exe monitor on" doesn't work

Tags: batch-file

The following batch file only works with monitor off, not monitor on:

```
@echo off
echo Monitor Off!
nircmd.exe monitor off
timeout /t 10
nircmd.exe monitor on
echo Monitor On!!!
pause
```

The monitor will turn off as expected, but it won't turn back on after 10s.

I am using Windows 10.  Does this approach need special hardware support?

Thank you.

Comment: 'nircmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Maybe. Did you try the asynch variant's ?

Comment: Nircmd ISN'T a batchfile but a program. Ask at their technical support.

Comment: @LotPings - i also tried 'nircmd.exe monitor async_on' but still no luck.

Answer (score 8):

Old thread, but this question wasn't answered yet and google brought me right here. I managed to figure it out as I guess I had a similar problem.

The trick is not to use the monitor on command since that is not supported on all bioses.

What you can do is to simulate a keystroke also using nircmd. 
The command I use now to power it on is "nircmd sendkeypress ctrl".
monitor off or async_off should usually work without problems.

I have scheduled it using the task scheduler, that seems to only work when you use the option "only when user is logged on", so this might help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found what worked for me is entering **two** sendpresskey tasks a few seconds apart.
I guess the first instance is too fast or insignificant ti wake the monitor.